# dojo dijit.form.Select IE8 overflow hidden

Tags: internet-explorer-8, dojo, overflow, dijit.form

So I'm using a dojo.form.Select control and it contains really long values something like ...

0029000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Which I want to truncate the selected value for space reasons to

002900000000000000

in my CSS I have set the following ...

```
#ddl.dijitSelect.glossSelect .dijitButtonText{
   display: inline-block;
   max-width: 470px;
   float: left;
   width:auto;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding-right:5px;
}
#ddl.dijitSelect.glossSelect .dijitButtonNode .dijitInline{
   display: inline-block;
   max-width:460px;
   float: left;
   width:auto;
   margin-right:5px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

This code works in all browsers EXCEPT IE8

Here is IE8
[image: ie8 select]

Here is everywhere else including other versions of IE 7 & 9
[image: everywhere else]